# How to clear badge counter on click of app icon in iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, apple-push-notifications

We have developed an ios app using phonegap and have implemented push notification functionality in our app.
Push notification works perfectly fine for us. We have configured push notification for both (alerts and badge) and both works fine.
When we click on the alert list it redirects us to the application and clears all the notifications from the alert list and also the badge counter is set to 0.

But when we click on the application icon(badge counter) it brings app to the foreground but the badge counter and alerts are not getting cleared.

We have used following code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method (in appdelegate.m file)that clears out the alerts and resets the badge only on-click of alerts

```
 application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

can anyone provide us the solution that shows same behaviour when we click on app icon with badge counter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038680/how-to-clear-push-notification-badge-count-in-ios try this

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To clear the badge count whenever the application becomes active use `delegate` method. You can use `UIApplicationDelegate` in AppDelegate.

call the **[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];** in either **applicationWillEnterForeground** nor **applicationDidBecomeActive**

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application

{
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
 }
```

**or**

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
}
```

**Swift**

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}
```

**or**

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}
```

**For Swift 3:**

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

**iOS 13 >**

```
func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where to call these function? No such method is present in our appdelegate file.

Comment: copy anyone of this method and paste into your **AppDelegate.m**

Comment: Swift4: UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

Answer (score 6):

If you are on iOS 13 supporting multiple windows, do the same on the method Scene Became active like this. 
This method is on SceneDelegate.

```
func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

Comment: Doing this in SceneDelegate rather than AppDelegate is what worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In Swift the following works to put in `func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication)`:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I reset it and remove it. You can call this in any vc assuming it has access to the tabBarController:

```
func resetAndRemoveTabBarBadge() {
    
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

    if let tabItems = tabBarController?.tabBar.items {

        let item = 4 // this is whichever tabBarItem you set the badge to appear on

        let tabItem = tabItems[item]
        tabItem.badgeValue = nil
    }
}
```