# Swift- Remove Push Notification Badge number?

Tags: swift

I am trying to remove the icon badge in swift, but PFInstallation doesn't seem to work anymore. How do I do this?

Answer (score 279, accepted):

You can "remove" the app badge icon by setting it to 0:

**Swift < 3.0**

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

**Swift 3.0+**

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

This question shows when you can use it: [How to clear push notification badge count in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038680/how-to-clear-push-notification-badge-count-in-ios)

Comment: So is it standard practice to reset it to 0 each time the app starts?

Comment: @ElgsQianChen really depends on what your app is supposed to do / what's best for your audience. That question is probably better served in the UX SO.

Comment: Second that. Perhaps you want to make sure the user actually dealt with the cause of the notification (e.g., _did_ read an unread message) before clearing it. Different apps deal with this differently. Some clear on launch, some clear on user action within the app.

Comment: `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0` with Swift 3

Comment: I think this makes sense ie. when the user logs out of the app.

Answer (score 28):

**Swift 4.2**

At the AppDelegate, just put this code:

```
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    }
```

Comment: If you use SceneDelegate, this code will not work. Use this instead 

func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}

Answer (score 17):

Swift 5

At the AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

Answer (score 17):

**Swift 5**

While you can put this in the AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, this will not clear the badge if the app is inactive and has moved to active.

If you wish to clear the badge regardless of the previous state you need to put this in the **SceneDelegate** instead of the AppDelegate.

```
func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}
```

Comment: Best answer here. Removes badge number either on fresh launch or when becoming active from the background!

Answer (score 6):

A more SwiftUI-oriented approach might be to listen for changes in the `@Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase` in the root view. Then, if the new phase is `.active`, set `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber` to `0` as discussed by the other answers.

Example Code:

```
@main
struct MRPApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newPhase in
                    if newPhase == .active {
                        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might actually want to perform the action when `newPhase` is `.background`, that way it clears any notifications that arrived when the user is in the app.