# How to reset badge count when app after app is opened?

Tags: notifications, swift3, ios10

In my notification function I set the badge count to one for each notification. How do I reset it to 0 when the app is opened?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift- Remove Push Notification Badge number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27769074/swift-remove-push-notification-badge-number)

Answer (score 2):

Call this:

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in AppDelegate.swift file.

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

In the Method

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
```