# Should my app be updated to Scene Delegate

Tags: ios, swift

Should my app be updated to Scene Delegate from App Delegate. My app supports ios 13.0 and up

Comment: using sceneDelegate is a good idea. it divides the load of appDelegate.

Comment: You are good go with `SceneDelegate` the reason you are supporting iOS version 13 and above

Comment: No reason not to. It's the new way to do things in iOS 13

Comment: Also, i have some data preparation in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  Should I move them to Scene Delegate or leave them in App Delegate? I have an check and if it is true, i present a different VC. Should it be moved to the Scene Delegate? @donnywals

Comment: Yes, that logic would belong in the scene delegate

Answer (score 3):

first you have to understand what is difference

You could think of them as the global and private versions. One is shared and the other is limited to the individual owner. In a way, they are exactly what you would expect by the names.

Multi-window support is happening

Next time you create a new Xcode project you’ll see your AppDelegate has split in two: AppDelegate.swift and SceneDelegate.swift. This is a result of the new multi-window support that landed with iPadOS, and effectively splits the work of the app delegate in two.

From iOS 13 onwards, your app delegate should:

1. Set up any data that you need for the duration of the app.
2. Respond to any events that focus on the app, such as a file being shared with you.
3. Register for external services, such as push notifications.
4. Configure your initial scenes.

In contrast, scene delegates are there to handle one instance of your app’s user interface. So, if the user has created two windows showing your app, you have two scenes, both backed by the same app delegate.

Keep in mind that these scenes are designed to work independently from each other. So, your application no longer moves to the background, but instead individual scenes do – the user might move one to the background while keeping another open.

at last I will say that you can go with `Scene Delegate`

Courtesy of https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/193/whats-new-in-ios-13

Comment: That is the future, I know, but I don’t plan my app to have multiple screens, only one. Should I still consider updating(adding) SceneDelegate?